# Why does `$v = () = split` return 1?

Tags: perl

`perldoc` says "a list assignment in scalar context returns the number of elements on the right-hand side of the list assignment" but when I try this code:

```
perl -e '$_="aaaaa";print $v=(()=split //)'
```

The output is `1` which makes me confused.  (The answer I expect is `5`.)

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split) documentation:

> When assigning to a list, if LIMIT is omitted, or zero, Perl supplies
>   a LIMIT one larger than the number of variables in the list <...>

Since you specify empty list, `split` only returns 1 result and this number of results is exactly what ends in your variable.

Comment: This is a weird freaking edge case.

Comment: @darch, perfectly documented, nothingless!

Answer (score 8):

`split` has some kind of crazy ultra-magic in it that allows it to know when it is on the right hand side of an assignment that has a list on the left hand side, and adjusts its behavior according to the number of items in that list.

This is described in `perlfunc` as being done "to avoid unnecessary work", but you've found an observable difference in behavior caused by that optimization.

To see some evidence of what happened, run your script through Deparse like this:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e '$_="aaaaa";print $v=(()=split //)'
```

**Update**: I went looking for the code that implements this, and it's not where I expected it to be. Actually the optimization is performed by the assignment operator (`op.c:Perl_newASSIGNOP`) . split doesn't know that much about its context.

Comment: very helpful. I know the reason now.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you assigning to an empty array? the `()=(split //)` bit. That's going to end up with - um, well, a mess. Or, in your case, an array with a size of one with not much in it.

Also, that's excessively obscure. perl has a sad reputation for being write-only, and all that modifying $_ and using it doesn't help others - or you - understand what is going on.

Try something like

```
perl -e '$v = (split //, "aaaaa"); print "$v\n"'
```

or, if you wish to replicate the behavior of your test:

```
perl -e '$v = () = (split //, "aaaaa"); print "$v\n"'
```

Comment: I just want to test the feature of perl, No practical use.

consider this code: perl -e '$_="aaaaa";print $v=(()=//g)' , It works as perldoc says

Comment: He's not assigning to an empty array, he's assigning to an empty list. I'd never let my code be reviewed by someone who doesn't know the difference :-) This trick is known as the "goatse operator" (see http://www.catonmat.net/blog/secret-perl-operators/#goatse) and it's often very useful.

Comment: a bad habit of mine - I do it with python tuples as well. But I strongly dislike a lot of the operators on that page. They add to the write-only-ness of the language.

Comment: @DaveCross, make me unsee that some call people call this goatse.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, but :

```
perl -e '$_="aaaaa";print $v=(split //)'
```

gives 5, as well as

```
perl -e '$_="aaaaa";print $v=(@x=split //)'
```

Maybe your left-value () is dropping additional array elements ?

**edit** : by the way :

```
perl -e '$_="aaaaa";print $v=(($x,$y)=split //)'
```

returns 3, because the right sight of the $v=... command gives :

(   $x  ,    $y   ,    ( a , a , a )   )

**So in your original case, `()=split //` returns ( ( a , a , a , a , a ) )  (which has only one element)**

*Edit :* bad array notation, and result was wrong because of a last minute changed of my test-case

Comment: Since when `split` or list operations return array references?

Comment: Lists are **not** arrays. (( a , a , a , a , a ))  is exactly equivalent to ( a , a , a , a , a ) and have 5 elements.

Comment: Well, I thought that `($x,$y,('a','a','a'))` has 3 elements, `($x,('a','a','a','a'))` has 2 elements, and `( ('a','a','a','a','a') )` has only one. Doesn't it make sense ?

Comment: @Orabîg, check out http://p3rl.org/perldata#List-value-constructors. There's also useful info on interpolation in this section. (And it also happens to explain exact `= () =` construct used in this question.)